# Why is a MongoDB update() slower than find() when no documents are matched and can this be changed?

Tags: mongodb, performance

Consider the following two approaches of (maybe) updating a bunch of records:

**Approach 1 ("find and maybe update"):**

```
let ids = db.getCollection("users").find({
    "status.lastActivity": {"$lte": timeoutDate}
}, {
    "fields": {"_id": 1}
}).fetch().map(doc => {
    doc = doc._id;
    return doc
});

if (ids.length) {
    db.getCollection("users").update({
        "_id": {"$in": ids}
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "status.idle": true
        }
    }, {
        "multi": true
    });
}
```

**Approach 2 ("directly update"):**

```
db.getCollection("users").update({
    "status.lastActivity": {"$lte": timeoutDate}
}, {
    "$set": {
        "status.idle": true
    }
}, {
    "multi": true
});
```

And now to keep it simple let's assume that there are never users with a smaller `status.lastActivity` than `timeoutDate` (so `ids` is also always an empty array).

In that case I get a **significantly** better performance with Approach 1. Like Approach 1 takes 0.1 to 2 ms while Approach 2 takes 40 to 80 ms.

My question now is, why is that the case? I would have assumed MongoDB is 'clever' enough to do things similar to Approach 1 under the hood when I actually use Approach 2 and doesn't waste resource when there actually is no record matched by the selector...

And can I change it somehow so that it would work that way? Or have I maybe some kind of wrong configuration which is causing this and I could get rid of? Because obviously writing things like in Approach 2 would be leaner...

Comment: Approach 2 will definitely be faster than approach 1. Execution time will be more or less the same at DB side but due to the fact that in approach 1, there are two network calls, there will be some extra overhead. 0.1 to 2ms for approach 1. Are you sure? I'm suspecting u tried approached 2 first and by the time everything was loaded in memory/cache which leads to faster approach 1

Comment: Sorry I missed one point in my last comment. As there will be no Ids in your cases. So in approach 1 as well, there will be only one network call.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in JS? `db.getCollection("users").find(` looks like it should return a Promise, and promises don't have length, so the update code that's gated by `ids.length` would never run.